# Xcode Encryption

Tags: iphone, xcode, encryption, upload

I am a newbie of iphone dev, I am going to upload the first app to app store. Before that, I want to if it need encryption before I upload, or is it .app itself is enough to protect the source code ?

please give me some advice , thanks x 10

Answer (score 2):

Submitting to the App Store only sends the compiled application bundle which includes resources such as icons and Nib files but does not include your source code.